# Result query based on every month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query to get the numbers of purchased items based on every month and country.

```
SELECT   COUNT( `country` ) as item,
         `country`,
         MONTH(purchase_date) AS Month,
         YEAR( purchase_date) AS year
FROM     charmy_purchase
WHERE    YEAR(purchase_date)='20112'
GROUP BY country,MONTH(purchase_date)
ORDER BY country ASC
```

I get this as result.

```
 item   country  Month  year
    2   India       5   2012
    1   India       6   2012
    1   Malasiya    5   2012
    3   Singapure   1   2012
    1   Singapure   4   2012
```

I don't want to get the 'counrty' as repeated. Is there any way to do it.

Comment: What would you want to resultset to look like? It's not very clear.

Comment: remove `MONTH(purchase_date)` from `GROUP BY country,MONTH(purchase_date)`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what output you expect. But you can remove `MONTH(purchase_date)` from `GROUP BY country,MONTH(purchase_date)`:

```
SELECT   COUNT( `country` ) as item,
     `country`,
     MONTH(purchase_date) AS Month,
     YEAR( purchase_date) AS year
FROM     charmy_purchase
WHERE    YEAR(purchase_date)='2012'
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY country ASC
```

This will give you distinct countries. But it will give you also any month and year if there a more for one country.

### Edit

If you want the months and year to be listed in one row comma seperated then try this:

```
SELECT   COUNT( `country` ) as item,
     `country`,
     group_concat(MONTH(purchase_date)) AS Months,
     YEAR( purchase_date) AS year
FROM     charmy_purchase
WHERE    YEAR(purchase_date)='2012'
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY country ASC
```

See this example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2052c/5)

Comment: Yeah I get distinct countries but for all the items the month shown as 5 (May) by default.

Comment: @Raj: And what output would you expect?

Comment: I expect country(india,..) has to come only once also months separatly. Ex:  india, item(2,1), month(5,6)

Comment: Yeah that's right but the items are just added. I want the items as monthEx: item(0,1)

Comment: @Raj: I don't know what you mean. Update your question with a proper example of the expected output.

Comment: I want to get the number of purchased items based on the country and every month. In the month of May I have purchased 3  and in June 2 in india. So the expected result is Item(3,2), Country(India), Month(may,june)

Answer (score 0):

Try group_concat, like this:

```
SELECT   COUNT( `country` ) as item,
         `country`,
         GROUP_CONCAT(MONTH(purchase_date)) AS Months,
         YEAR( purchase_date) AS year
FROM     charmy_purchase
WHERE    YEAR(purchase_date)='2012'
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY country ASC
```

Comment: in the month field i get "[BLOB - 5 B],[BLOB - 1 B],[BLOB - 13 B]". I don't know what it means. And the items is just added(1+2)